# Load balance M/Monit collector

Tags: monitoring, load-balancing, monit

I am new to Monit monitoring system. Can we load balance mmonit collector (two instances) to avoid single point failure.

I mean if monit collector (instance) is down, whole monitoring system will be down.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your M/Monit collector is down, you won't be able to poll monitoring data from the servers. Make sure your monitoring server is available.

However, your servers will still have local Monit daemons running. Alerts from those systems will continue to work, as they do not depend on the central collector.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Monitoring will always up then, irrespective of M/Monit collector status. I think we will just loose access to Web UI in this case. Is any other monitoring tool where we can load balance collector/server like Zabbix, Cacti? Can we load balance Zabbix or Cacti Server?

Comment: I don't think most people worry about high-availability of their monitoring system. There comes a point where that's not feasible.